# How can I use cache with Rails 5.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails.cache.fetch(ranking_cache_key, expires_in: 12.hours) do
  data
end
```

I want to cache ranking data to Rails.cache. Right after this code, I am sure I can cache data because exists? method return true. But I did "rails runner" command second time, I don't get any cache data from the below code.

```
Rails.cache.fetch(ranking_cache_key)
```

How can I cache data for 12 hours? I am using Rails 5.2.1

and in dev environment file

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes, expires_in: 12.minutes }

config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
}
```

Comment: Do you have this line in your `development.rb` file? `if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?`

Comment: `memory_store` does not share cached data between processes, try different `cache_store`?see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memorystore